# Deleting strings after a certain column in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a set of data which looks like this

XXXYYY,20151001,09:16,17370.40,17390.60,17362.40,17381.00,50,0

What I want to do is, deleting everything after the value 17381.00 i.e delete ",50,0".I have 7500 rows of such data and column number after 17381.00 is 61 in all rows.

What i am looking for is to able to delete everything from column 61.

The expected output is XXXYYY,20151001,09:16,17370.40,17390.60,17362.40,17381.00

Comment: How many total columns does the file have?

Comment: Are `,50,0` the last 2 columns on each lines?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^((?:[^,]*,){59}[^,]*),.*$
Replace: $1
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
^
(
    (?:[^,]*,){59}  match and capture 'xxx,' 59 times
    [^,]*           match and capture 'xxx' (no comma)
)
,                   match a ,
.*                  consume the remainder of the line
$
```

Then, we replace with just the capture group `$1`, effectively removing columns 61 onwards.

### Demo